# Why Gawain and Escanor powers are so different when they had the same grace?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Supposedly Escanor and Gawain had the same grace (Sunshine). However, Escanor is much more powerful (he had no problem with Galand) , he grows bigger when closer to the noon (Gawain is always the same size) and he doesnt run out of magic power, when Gawain does and when it happens she gets smaller.

Why Gawain and Escanor powers are so different when they had the same grace?